# Check IF value matched with the array - PHP

Tags: php

Can you help me with this?
I want my username and password matched with the array I set. Here's the code.

```
    $users = array (
                0 => 
                array (
                  'username' => '10010',
                  'password' => '01019'
                ),
                1 => 
                array (
                  'username' => '10011',
                  'password' => '01151'
                ),
                2 => 
                array (
                  'username' => '10012',
                  'password' => '01214'
                ),
            );

if($user_id == match with 'username' && $password_id == match with inputted username's 'password')
```

Thank you! :D

Comment: [array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$users = array (
    0 =>
        array (
            'username' => '10010',
            'password' => '01019'
        ),
    1 =>
        array (
            'username' => '10011',
            'password' => '01151'
        ),
    2 =>
        array (
            'username' => '10012',
            'password' => '01214'
        ),
);

/* Change the values in $thisuser array below to test out the result:- */
$thisuser = array (
        'username' => '10010',
        'password' => '01011'
        );

/* This part does the checking:- */
if (is_numeric(array_search($thisuser,$users,true))) { echo "Match found."; }
 else { echo "Match not found."; };

?>
```

Comment: Glad that it helps. Note that i use is_numeric function before array_search, so that your first record (array 0) still holds true.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`array_search()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

```
if (array_search(['username' => $user_id, 'password' => $password_id], $users)) {
  echo 'Found';
} else {
  echo 'Not found';
}
```

https://3v4l.org/cDh53

---

If you find a dupe which doesn't use a loop, let me know happy to delete. I did look.

Comment: I don't know why but it only accept the username and password of the last value on array. Example, it only accepts the 2 => 
                array (
                  'username' => '10012',
                  'password' => '01214'
                )

Comment: my example link shows that's not the case, its matching index 1

Comment: besides, if that's all you have in the array, like the original code and question then array_search is fine.. but if you have other stuff in the array you're not showing then its not suitable and you should use a foreach like above, or if its a really large array use a binary search, or better a database query

Comment: This does works! Thank you for the answer and help :D

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$users = array (
    0 =>
        array (
            'username' => '10010',
            'password' => '01019'
        ),
    1 =>
        array (
            'username' => '10011',
            'password' => '01151'
        ),
    2 =>
        array (
            'username' => '10012',
            'password' => '01214'
        ),
);

$user_id = '10011';
$password_id = '01151';

foreach ($users as $values) {
    if($user_id == $values['username'] && $password_id == $values['password']) {
        echo "Match Found";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for me. I'll check it if with a lot of array values. Wish I could upvote this.